# Javascript - Question regarding Set Timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As per my understanding, the below function should print **5 five times** because of **hoisting**. But instead, it prints **6 five times**.

Question is, how come it prints **6** when the loop's limit is `<=5`?

```js
function () {
  for ( var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout( function() {
      console.log(i); //  this should print '5' five times 
    }, i * 1000)
  }
}
```

Comment: the for loop stops after the `i++` occurs which meets the condition for exiting (i.e. 6 > 5) - at that point, the value of `i` has incremented to 6 already and about a second later the value is printed

Comment: When the loop finishes the value of `i` is `6`. The log executes after the loop finishes hence printing 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop stops after the `i++` occurs which meets the condition for exiting (i.e. `6 > 5`) - at that point, the value of `i` has incremented to `6` already and about a second later the value of `i` is printed

Answer (score 2):

It prints 6 because that’s the value of `i` when the loop exits.

Consider the flow at the end of the loop’s run, when `i` is 4:

- Is i <= 5? Yes.
- execute the body
- increment i to 5
- Is i <= 5? Yes.
- execute the body
- increment i to 6
- Is i <= 5? No.
- exit the loop

Comment: And because of hoisting of 'i', it the CB refers to the latest value in the memory space and prints 6 each time. 
Thanks alot, makes sense now.

Comment: It's because of the setTimeout rather than the loop itself.

Comment: The question was why it's 6 instead of 5, not why it prints the same number each time. The setTimeout is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the increment you apply sol =>

```
function num() {
  for ( var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    setTimeout( function() {
      console.log(i); //  this should print '5' five times 
    }, i * 1000)
  }
}
num()
```